# What can I use as an internal identifier in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server

First a bit of background:

I developed a method of retrieving rows from a table in SQL in batches or pages, by using `IEnumerable` and `yield`. It works great when you need read only access but not so well when you need to do updates to the underlying data as well.

So I wrote a method that takes in a generic `DataTable`, and builds up an update statement which then gets passed to SQL along with the entire `DataTable` as a table valued parameter.

The method looks like this:

```
string[] validColumns = SQL_Columns.Split(',');
    foreach(DataColumn column in p_UpdatesTable.Columns)
    {
      if(!validColumns.Contains(column.ColumnName))
      {
        throw new Exception("Column '" + column.ColumnName + "' is not valid for this table");
      }
    }

    //Establish SQL Connection
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
      sqlConnection.Open();
      StringBuilder commandBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      commandBuilder.Append("UPDATE Table SET ");
      List<string> columnsToUpdate = new List<string>(p_UpdatesTable.Columns.Count);
      foreach(DataColumn column in p_UpdatesTable.Columns)
      {
        if (!column.ColumnName.Equals("UID", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
          StringBuilder columnBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          columnBuilder.Append(column.ColumnName);
          columnBuilder.Append(" = U.");
          columnBuilder.Append(column.ColumnName);
          columnsToUpdate.Add(columnBuilder.ToString());
        }
      }
      commandBuilder.Append(string.Join(",", columnsToUpdate.ToArray()));
      commandBuilder.Append(" FROM @UpdateTable AS U WHERE UID = U.UID");
      using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandBuilder.ToString(), sqlConnection))
      {
        SqlParameter updateTableParameter = sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("UpdateTable", SqlDbType.Structured);
        updateTableParameter.Value = p_UpdatesTable;
        int rowsAffected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if(rowsAffected != p_UpdatesTable.Rows.Count)
        {
          throw new Exception("Update command affected " + rowsAffected + " rows out of the " + p_UpdatesTable.Rows.Count + " expected.");
        }
      }
      sqlConnection.Dispose();
    }
```

I then built this method to populate the update table:

```
private void AddUpdate(ref DataTable p_UpdateTable, string p_ColumnName, long p_uid, object p_value)
{
  if(!StronglyTypedDataset.Columns.Contains(p_ColumnName))
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("Table '" + p_ColumnName + "' does not exist in table", "p_ColumnName");
  }
  if(!p_UpdateTable.Columns.Contains(p_ColumnName))
  {
    DataColumn columnToAdd = p_UpdateTable.Columns.Add(p_ColumnName);
    columnToAdd.DataType = StronglyTypedDataset.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.ColumnName.Equals(p_ColumnName)).First().DataType;
  }
  var existingRow = p_UpdateTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => Convert.ToInt64(r["UID"]) == p_uid).FirstOrDefault();
  if(existingRow != null)
  {
    existingRow[p_ColumnName] = p_value;
  }
  else
  {
    DataRow newRow = p_UpdateTable.NewRow();
    newRow["UID"] = p_uid;
    newRow[p_ColumnName] = p_value;
    p_UpdateTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
  }
}
```

There are a few times where I need to call this so this is more of a convenience method than anything else.

Now the problem: there is a possibility where I add a bunch of columns and values for one UID, but for another I might add more columns or not add values for existing columns. The problem with this is the update as it is will obliterate whatever is in the database already with a null value, which I don't want unless I explicitly say "make this null".

I was thinking of getting around this by supplying a value as a default, which I can then check for in my update statement and then using a `CASE` in the `UPDATE` statement that checks for this value, and using the original value (so in essence I could just ignore the "U." before the column name). The problem is that the table is generic so there could be anything in there, and in the case of actual data that somehow matches my default value, things would break.

I should note that this update table will be built up into a batch and a batch updated at once, not on a row by row basis.

Is there a value that is guaranteed not to be used, perhaps a GUID (I know there could still be a collision) or something like that?

**An example:**

Say my table looks like this after one row:

```
      |  UID   | column 1 | column 2 |
row 1 |    1   |   x      |    y     |
```

On the second row it looks like this:

```
      |  UID   | column 1 | column 2 | column 3 |
row 1 |    1   |   x      |    y     |    ?     |
row 2 |    2   |   x      |    y     |    z     |
```

The value for row 1 column 3 never gets set, so it gets defaulted to null. When I use my update statement, SQL will go and set that value to null even if there is something already in the table, but I don't want it to update the field for that row at all since I didn't specify a value for it.

I want to be able to put a value in place of the `?` instead of it defaulting to null, so then I can change the update statement to something like `UPDATE Table SET Column1 = U.Column1, Column2 = U.Column2, Column3 = CASE WHEN U.Column3 = somevalue THEN Column3 ELSE U.Column3 END FROM @UpdateTable U`.

Comment: Based on your edit, I think the only sane way to do this is, unfortunately, row by row. The reason is that the logic really is on a row-by-row basis. Some rows have multiple columns to update, some don't. Just issue an update statement for each row that needs to change, with only the columns mentioned that need to change.

Comment: I was really hoping to avoid that, since that would be a lot of back and forth between the application and SQL. I don't actually expect this to be a problem with the code I'm planning on using, but I do note it as a caveat/vulnerability that I was hoping to plug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up taking a slightly different route, not using an identifier but using another column entirely.

My `AddUpdate` looks like this now:

```
private void AddUpdate(DataTable p_UpdateTable, string p_ColumnName, long p_uid, object p_value)
{
  if (!StronglyTypedDataSet.Columns.Contains(p_ColumnName))
  {
    throw new ArgumentException("Table '" + p_ColumnName + "' does not exist in table", "p_ColumnName");
  }
  if (!p_UpdateTable.Columns.Contains(p_ColumnName))
  {
    var matchingColumn = StronglyTypedDataSet.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(c => c.ColumnName.Equals(p_ColumnName)).First();
    DataColumn columnToAdd = p_UpdateTable.Columns.Add(p_ColumnName, matchingColumn.DataType);
    columnToAdd.MaxLength = matchingColumn.MaxLength;
    DataColumn setNullColumn = p_UpdateTable.Columns.Add(p_ColumnName + "_null", typeof(bool));
    setNullColumn.DefaultValue = false;
  }
  var existingRow = p_UpdateTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => Convert.ToInt64(r["UID"]) == p_uid).FirstOrDefault();
  if (existingRow != null)
  {
    existingRow[p_ColumnName] = p_value;
    if (p_value == null || p_value == DBNull.Value)
    {
      existingRow[p_ColumnName + "_null"] = true;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    DataRow newRow = p_UpdateTable.NewRow();
    newRow["UID"] = p_uid;
    newRow[p_ColumnName] = p_value;
    if (p_value == null || p_value == DBNull.Value)
    {
      newRow[p_ColumnName + "_null"] = true;
    }
    p_UpdateTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
  }
}
```

This way, if a column gets defaulted to null because it gets added only after some rows get added to the table, I can do a check in my update statement that doesn't update the value.

The update statement looks like this now:

```
string[] validColumns = SQL_Columns.Split(',');
    var trimmed = validColumns.Select(c => c.Trim());
    foreach(DataColumn column in p_UpdatesTable.Columns)
    {
      if(!column.ColumnName.EndsWith("_null") && !trimmed.Contains(column.ColumnName))
      {
        throw new Exception("Column '" + column.ColumnName + "' is not valid for table");
      }
    }
    string tableTypeName = "dbo.UpdateSpecific" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "");
    StringBuilder tableTypeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    tableTypeBuilder.Append("CREATE TYPE ");
    tableTypeBuilder.Append(tableTypeName);
    tableTypeBuilder.Append(" AS TABLE (");
    List<string> tableTypeColumns = new List<string>(p_UpdatesTable.Columns.Count);

    StringBuilder commandBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    commandBuilder.Append("UPDATE Table SET ");
    List<string> columnsToUpdate = new List<string>(p_UpdatesTable.Columns.Count);
    foreach (DataColumn column in p_UpdatesTable.Columns)
    {
      //build command to create table type
      StringBuilder columnTypeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      columnTypeBuilder.Append("[");
      columnTypeBuilder.Append(column.ColumnName);
      columnTypeBuilder.Append("] ");
      if(column.DataType == typeof(int))
      {
        columnTypeBuilder.Append("INT");
      }
      else if(column.DataType == typeof(long))
      {
        columnTypeBuilder.Append("BIGINT");
      }
      else if(column.DataType == typeof(bool))
      {
        columnTypeBuilder.Append("BIT");
      }
      else if(column.DataType == typeof(string))
      {
        columnTypeBuilder.Append("VARCHAR(");
        columnTypeBuilder.Append(column.MaxLength);
        columnTypeBuilder.Append(")");
      }
      else if(column.DataType == typeof(byte[]))
      {
        columnTypeBuilder.Append("IMAGE");
      }
      tableTypeColumns.Add(columnTypeBuilder.ToString());

      //build actual update statement
      if (!column.ColumnName.Equals("UID", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && !column.ColumnName.EndsWith("_null"))
      {
        StringBuilder columnBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        columnBuilder.Append(column.ColumnName);
        columnBuilder.Append(" = (CASE WHEN U.");
        columnBuilder.Append(column.ColumnName);
        columnBuilder.Append(" IS NULL THEN (CASE WHEN ISNULL(U.");
        columnBuilder.Append(column.ColumnName);
        columnBuilder.Append("_null, 0) = 1 THEN U.");
        columnBuilder.Append(column.ColumnName);
        columnBuilder.Append(" ELSE C.");
        columnBuilder.Append(column.ColumnName);
        columnBuilder.Append(" END) ELSE U.");
        columnBuilder.Append(column.ColumnName);
        columnBuilder.Append(" END)");
        columnsToUpdate.Add(columnBuilder.ToString());
      }
    }
    tableTypeBuilder.Append(string.Join(",", tableTypeColumns.ToArray()));
    tableTypeBuilder.Append(")");

    commandBuilder.Append(string.Join(",", columnsToUpdate.ToArray()));
    commandBuilder.Append(" FROM Table AS C JOIN @UpdateTable AS U ON C.UID = U.UID");

    //Establish SQL Connection
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(context.strContext[(int)eCCE_Context._CONNECTION_STRING]))
    {
      sqlConnection.Open();
      try
      {
        using (SqlCommand createTableTypeCommand = new SqlCommand(tableTypeBuilder.ToString(), sqlConnection))
        {
          createTableTypeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandBuilder.ToString(), sqlConnection))
        {
          SqlParameter updateTableParameter = sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@UpdateTable", SqlDbType.Structured);
          updateTableParameter.Value = p_UpdatesTable;
          updateTableParameter.TypeName = tableTypeName;
          int rowsAffected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
          if (rowsAffected != p_UpdatesTable.Rows.Count)
          {
            throw new Exception("Update command affected " + rowsAffected + " rows out of the " + p_UpdatesTable.Rows.Count + " expected.");
          }
        }
      }
      finally
      {
        string dropStatement = "IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types st JOIN sys.schemas ss ON st.schema_id = ss.schema_id WHERE st.name = N'"+ tableTypeName.Substring(tableTypeName.IndexOf(".")+1) +"' AND ss.name = N'dbo') DROP TYPE " + tableTypeName;
        using (SqlCommand dropTableTypeCommand = new SqlCommand(dropStatement, sqlConnection))
        {
          dropTableTypeCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
      }
      sqlConnection.Dispose();
    }
```

Tested and working :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make yourself a little `Maybe<T>` that can either be an actual value for `T`, in which case you push through the update, or it could be a special not-a-value. It could look something like this:

```
public sealed class Maybe<T> {
    private readonly T value;
    private readonly bool hasValue;

    private Maybe() {
        hasValue = false;
    }

    public readonly Maybe<T> Nothing = new Maybe();

    public Maybe(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        hasValue = true;
    }

    public T Value {
        get {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public bool HasValue {
        get {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Which you could use like this:

```
private void AddUpdate<T>(DataTable p_UpdateTable, string p_ColumnName, long p_uid, Maybe<T> p_value) {
    // ...
    if(existingRow != null) {
        if(p_value.HasValue)
            existingRow[p_ColumnName] = p_value.Value;
    }
    else {
        DataRow newRow = p_UpdateTable.NewRow();
        newRow["UID"] = p_uid;
        if(p_value.HasValue)
            newRow[p_ColumnName] = p_value.Value;
        p_UpdateTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
    // ...
}
```

You don't need the `ref` for the `DataTable` parameter, by the way.

Comment: Yes that will work within the code, but when I give SQL that in an update it doesn't know what a `Maybe` is.

Comment: @Logan: you won't assign the `Maybe` object itself to the `DataRow`, but rather the value inside of it, which is going to be a regular type. I updated my answer to fix the bug.

Comment: that's not the problem. This is running in batches. So if I have row 1 with column x, y, z and row 2 with w, x, z, only row 2 has a value for w and row 1 gets defaulted to null. SQL will stick the null in w for row 1, where I need it to ignore updating w for row 1 and only update it for row 2 since I only *specified* a value for row 2.

Comment: @Logan, I admin that I don't fully understand how your process works, but based on what I think I understand, I would suggest that you update the data row by row, so that you can update different fields for each row.

Comment: I edited my question with an example, hopefully that makes more sense of what I'm trying to accomplish.